# capturing events with applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

is it at all possible for an applescript (or perhaps some other script) to receive notifications when other (unrelated) applications change state, i.e. close, minimize?
The goal is to maintain a list of the 5 most recently closed or minimized applications

Answer (score 0):

A way to get your triggers set up might be http://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2011/01/28/how-to-run-an-applescript-when-switching-to-battery-power/

The following script'll get you all applications that are currently minimized (other than Finder for some reason, definite bug), you could set this to run at intervals, or even set it to run in the background continuously (performance'll be effected I imagine), but hopefully it gets you a little bit closer to a solution (realizing of course that this doesn't really tackle the trigger on state change for any window issue)

```
property top5 : {"None", "None", "None", "None", "None"}
property oldest : 0


tell application "System Events" to set _list to (name of application processes)

repeat with i from 1 to number of _list
    set current_name to item i of _list

    if top5 does not contain current_name then
        tell application "System Events" to tell application process current_name to set win_num to (number of every window)
        if not win_num is 0 then
            try
                tell application current_name
                    set _windows to every window
                    repeat with i from 1 to number of _windows
                        set this_window to item i of _windows

                        try
                            log "mini"
                            if miniaturized of this_window is true then
                                my addNewToTop5(current_name)
                                exit repeat
                            end if
                        end try

                        try
                            log "collapsed"
                            if collapsed of this_window is true then
                                my addNewToTop5(current_name)
                                exit repeat
                            end if
                        end try

                    end repeat
                end tell
            end try
        end if

    end if

end repeat

log top5

on oldestOfTop5()
if oldest is 5 then
    set oldest to 1
else
    set oldest to oldest + 1
end if
return oldest
end oldestOfTop5

on addNewToTop5(_item)
set item oldestOfTop5() of top5 to _item
end addNewToTop5
```

Answer (score 0):

You really can't do this with applescript. If you know objective-c though it's fairly trivial. NSWorkspace posts notifications about a lot of stuff, and among them are everything you want to know about applications hiding, activating etc. Take a look at the class documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for all of the notifications you can get.

Basically all you'd have to do is write a small background application that receives those notifications and then you can do whatever you want with them. A simple call like the one below would register you for all of the notifications and then a simple "if statement" in the "nsworkspaceNotification:" method could be used to figure out which ones you were receiving and allow you to take an action on them.

```
[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(nsworkspaceNotification:) name:nil object:nil];
```